Prevent matplotlib from redrawing while data are being added
I was trying to plot some points (via geopandas) and discovered adding them gets progressively slower and slower up to the point where each takes a second and more at only few hundreds. This is harly usable and definitely abnormal.
My guess is, matplotlib redraws everything everytime new data is added to the figure, which is backed up by cProfile:
   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
   143915  479.433    0.003  479.602    0.003 collections.py:352(draw)
   137549    0.238    0.000  478.297    0.003 collections.py:1014(draw)
...

Searching for a solution to this problem proved hard. I have no idea why the library would redraw on every change when nothing is being displayed. There are some recommendations to use a static backend and to switch to non-interactive mode. Using corresponding configurations however does nothing for the performance, as the library uses static backend and non-interactive mode by default.
Stepping through the source I am seeing no point at which interactive mode would be even considered, or a call to a draw() could be conditionally intercepted.
Is there a way to make matplotlib postpone drawing until all data are added to the plot and are ready to be shown?
Here's the script to reproduce the issue. Let's see if it makes a difference.
from pandas import DataFrame
from geopandas import GeoDataFrame, points_from_xy
from matplotlib import pyplot

def plot_point(figure, geodata):
    geodata.plot(ax=figure.gca())

figure = pyplot.figure()

data = DataFrame({})
lat = 0
lon = 1
geodata = GeoDataFrame(data, geometry=points_from_xy([lon], [lat]))

for i in range(300):
    print(i)
    plot_point(figure, geodata)


Can you show some minimal example of what you are trying to do?

@TomMcLean What do you mean? I feel showing my call to GeoDataFrame.plot() would add nothing to the question.

If you KNOW that showing your call to GeoDataFrame.plot would add nothing to the question, OK. Otherwise showing a bit of your code is not a bad idea.

Like, any bit of code?

I am not against showing relevant bits, but can we start with some hypothesis of what part of it is the issue?

Let's say I show the way I call the plot(), what are we expecting to find there? Is there even a way for me to call it that would cause it to take over a second to complete? If it is up to me to assess its relevance, at this point I would say it has nothin to do with the issue.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I hope not everyone in this community downvotes a question they have nothing to add to. Doesn't sound like something I would want to be a part of.

With the code people can better understand your issue and hopefully one of them will find the solution. The problem is probably due to the loop. Why not put all your data in one final datframe and when everything is there draw the plot.

@rehaqds That is on a list of workarounds. I would prefer to learn how to use the library properly.

I cannot reproduce with the provided code, Matplotlib v3.9.2 and Geopandas v1.0.1. Collection.draw is called zero times. If I show or save the figure then Collection.draw is called 300 times.

"I would prefer to learn how to use the library properly." Avoid the loop, commit your data in a single call to the plotting routines.

@gboffi is that documented somewhere?

The answer is "not out of the box". There are no settings to disable redraws in the library.
Some backends might batch redraws as a side effect. The base implementation, which Agg and most others use, redraws whenever it can. The comments never claim to provide any protection from that, but leave it as an option to inheriting classes.
So it is possible to implement a custom backend with a more conservative redraw strategy and use that. In my case the following was enough:
from matplotlib.backend_bases import _Backend
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg, _BackendAgg

class FigureCanvasAggLazy(FigureCanvasAgg):
    def draw_idle(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pass # No intermediate draws needed if you are only saving to a file

@_Backend.export
class _BackendAggLazy(_BackendAgg):
    FigureCanvas = FigureCanvasAggLazy

